# APEX - Click able Form Rows with SQL Query

Tags: sql, forms, dynamic, oracle-apex

I want to be able to have a link, or make an entire row, click able to go to a dynamically generated report based on a value from that row

For instance: If I click on a row from a "modules" table I want to be able to show all the records from the "assessments" table where the module code is equal to the module code of the row clicked.

Is this, or something with a similar outcome, achievable in APEX?

Module Table:

```
create table module
(module_code varchar2(10) not null primary key,
module_name varchar2(35) not null,
lecturer_code varchar2(6) not null references lecturer(lecturer_code),
module_number_assessments number(1) not null,
module_moderator varchar2(25));
```

Assessments Table:

```
create table assessment
(module_code varchar2(10) not null references module(module_code),
assessment_no number(1) not null,
assessment_name varchar2(35) not null,
assessment_weight number(3) not null,
assessment_filename varchar2(50),
assessment_status number(1) not null references assessment_status(status),
primary key(module_code, assessment_no));
```

Modules Page source:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM module m
WHERE
(
   upper(lecturer_code) = upper(:APP_USER)
   AND (SELECT login_type FROM login WHERE upper(login_username) =  upper(:APP_USER)) = 'U'
)
OR
(
   (SELECT login_type FROM login WHERE upper(login_username) = upper(:APP_USER)) = 'A'
)
```

Comment: post your source query for your modules table and assessments table and from there ill guide you step by step =)

Comment: No worries, I'll send that over shortly :)

Comment: @brenners1302 I've added the table structures

Comment: sorry for the late reply........holidays.=).do you have experience using oracle apex?if yes, i need you to do the basic.the pages which has the report for modules table and assessment table. I assume they are in different page.after creating those report i need you to post the source query of those report.

Comment: @brenners1302 Not a problem! :) I'm a beginner but I think I can do as you ask, I'll add it to the post now.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that your Interactive report for `module` is in Page `X` and interactive report for `assessment` is on Page `Y`.

> - First you have to choose what column in the module report will be the column link(if the column is clicked, it will redirect you to another page). You can choose any column, In this case, I prefer `module_code` as the column link since it is the foreign key for the assesment table.
> - Next, Go to **REPORT ATTRIBUTES** then click the column `module_code`
> - Then, Search for the **Column Link** section
> - Then, under the **Column Link** section,
>   In the **Link Text** write #MODULE_CODE#
>   In the **Target**, choose URL
>   In the **URL**, put this code

```
 javascript: window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:Y:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::PY_MODULE_CODE:#MODULE_CODE#','_blank');
```

Note that `Y` is the page where you show the report for assessment table so just change `Y` to your chosen page.

If Y = 2 then

```
javascript: window.open('f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::P2_MODULE_CODE:#MODULE_CODE#','_blank');
```

> - Then Apply changes.
> - Then, go to page `Y` then create a **page item**, **type = hidden field**, **name = PY_MODULE_CODE**
> - Then edit the source of assessment table and write this code:

```
SELECT module_code,
       assessment_no ,
       assessment_name ,
       assessment_weight,
       assessment_filename ,
       assessment_status

FROM assessment
WHERE module_code = :PY_MODULE_CODE;
```

> - Under the Source Query, in the Page Items to Submit, write PY_MODULE_CODE
> - Then apply changes.
> - Then see how it goes =)

Note:Change Y to the corresponding page from your application.
e.g.name= P2_MODULE_CODE.

just comment if you encounter any errors